# For what specific reason should we use "force_remount=True" in colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, mount, drive

What does it change if we do "force_remount=True" or force_remount=False" or when we do not precise it in google colab ? What are the specific reasons that could explain that we use it compared to a situation when we do not use it ?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `force_remount` parameter is useful when you want to explicitly remount Google Drive within your notebook, either to ensure a fresh connection or to update access. You may want to forcibly remount the drive in instances where your Drive connection times out or when you suspect issues with the existing connection. Additionally, it's important to note that notebooks edited by another user do not automatically remount Google Drive. If it were to automatically remount when another user edits the notebook, it would essentially grant access to the notebook owner's Google Drive to potentially unauthorized users. Forcibly remounting your Google Drive is typically most appropriate when you are the sole user of your notebook.

If you are curious, you can quickly access the source code for the `drive` module by hovering your mouse over the `drive` module or the `mount` method in your notebook and click on 'View source'. You'll notice that the `force_remount` parameter is set to `False` by default.

- Mounting Google Drive locally ([link to Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA))
- Why does `drive.mount()` sometimes fail saying "timed out", and why
  do I/O operations in `drive.mount()`-mounted folders sometimes fail?
  ([link to Google Colab FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#drive-timeout))
- Why does "Mount Drive" sometimes insert code into the notebook? ([link
  to Google Colab FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#drive-mount-code-cell))

Answer (score 0):

I think sometimes the file tab lags behind in refreshing after you make some file changes in your google drive.
In such cases, you might consider remounting Google Drive with `force_remount=True`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

force_remount=True instructs Colab to forcefully remount Google Drive. This prompts you to reauthenticate, and the new mount replaces any previous mounts.